# Are airport emergency vehicles' sirens louder than normal?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport

So there I was this afternoon, sitting in my car waiting on my wife's flight to get in to Dulles Airport (IAD), in the cell phone parking lot. I was listening to some music on the radio when the rescue vehicle (ambulance) got a call to go somewhere. I know this, because it absolutely deafened me. Turns out (one of) the firehouse is right next to the lot. I've been in front of firehouses before when trucks have gotten calls and they weren't THAT loud.

This started me wondering if airport emergency vehicles have extra-loud sirens, due to the greater than normal ambient noise on an airport?

Comment: Unable to get complete answer. The best I could find: [FAA regulations stating "The siren
speaker will be rated at 100 watts minimum".](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5220_10e.pdf) (3.10.6.1, page 65) The [DC regulations say a siren on an emergency vehicle must be "capable of giving a signal audible under normal conditions from a distance of not less than five hundred feet"](https://fems.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/fems/publication/attachments/Bull.%2091%20Excerpts%20from%20DCMR%20Title%2018.pdf). (712.2, page 1) Unsure how to convert between them.

Comment: A 100W speaker can provide an audio signal around 120dB. Which is almost twice as loud as a home TV turned up to maximum volume. at 85dB staying near the vicinity of the source would damage your hearing

Comment: If you really want to move the traffic out of the way, use a Federal Q2B electromechanical siren. 128 db and so loud it's banned by the FDNY for being too loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airport emergency vehicles are not required to have louder sirens than off airport vehicles, at least in the US.

Emergency vehicle sirens conform to standards from various entities, one of which is Federal [NIJ Standard-OSOl.00](https://www.ojp.gov/pdffiles1/nij/77185.pdf). Two levels are specified, Class A and B. Class A is

> A-weighted on-axis sound level of 120 dB and meet the off-axis sound
> level and other requirements of paragraph 4.3

Class B has the same requirements at 115db. Louder class A sirens may be mounted in less than optimal locations as under a hood. The less powerful Class B must be mounted in an unobstructed location, as in a forward facing roof mount.

Airport emergency equipment with a siren is required to have a [100w rated speaker](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5220_10e.pdf) if purchased using Federal Airport Improvement grant funds, which pretty much means all of them will conform.

> 3.10.6.1 Siren. The vehicle will be equipped with an electronic siren system. The amplifier unit will include volume control and selection of "Radio," "PA," "Manual," "Yelp," "Wail," and "Hi-Lo" (European) modes, and a magnetic noise canceling microphone. The amplifier, microphone, and controls will be within reach of the driver and the turret operator. Siren activating foot switches will be located in front of the driver and the turret operator. The siren speaker will be rated at 100 watts minimum and will be located in a guarded position as low and as far forward on the vehicle as practical.

Looking at an example [manufacturer's products](https://carson-mfg.com/product-specs-chart/), every siren had a 100w rated speaker and conformed to a Class A rating, so these seem to be functionally identical in performance. I found no Class B sirens; there is likely little difference in manufacturing cost and so does not justify an installation constraint.