# What is a "cell phone parking lot"?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, cell-phone

[This question about sirens](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70196/are-airport-emergency-vehicles-sirens-louder-than-normal) refers to a "cell phone parking lot." I know use of cell phones is prohibited on planes; is this true in most of the airport as well?

Comment: This belongs on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An airport "cell phone parking lot" is a location (on/near the airport) where someone in their car can park while they are awaiting the arrival of someone they are planning on picking up after their flight has arrived.

The term "cell phone parking lot" comes from the idea that once the arriving passenger is ready to be picked up they will call (by cell phone/text) the person who is waiting for them at the airport (in the cell phone parking lot).  Then that person can leave the cell phone parking lot and drive to the (often very crowded) arrival section of the airport and pick up the arriving passenger.

This reduces the automobile congestion near the baggage claim/arrival section of the airport.

Comment: "This reduces the automobile congestion near the baggage claim/arrival section of the airport." And also keeps people from driving around while on the phone. Illegal in many places, and usually dangerous.